# CSS animation issue

Tags: css, google-chrome, animation

I'm working on an online cv, and I have a couple of animations going on...
Among them is a head-line animation which animates through 3 headlines.
This doesn't work in chrome, and I can't figure out why..

I've narrowed it down to the css... It's the -webkit-animation-play-state: paused, that just doesn't work in chrome...

I don't think it's the -webkit- prefix that is wrong, cause it works well in safari..

Check out the page in chrome and then in another browser, then you'll get the idea..

I hope someone could have a possible answer, without me posting A LOT of code..
I cant just say that the animation code for the headlines is similar to a lot of other animations that works great, also i chrome...

Please help.

Link: [www.sipri.dk](http://www.sipri.dk)

Comment: Provide example code, please. and a jsfiddle, ideally

Comment: If you can't narrow down your html to just the basic parts of the issue and need to post "A LOT of code", that's your first problem.

Comment: yeah, sorry... As said I've narrowed it down to the -webkit-animation-play-state... Actually, was just hoping that someone else may have had the exact same problem based on how my page looks in chrome...

Comment: is it pure css or is it using js to cycle through the images?

Comment: using js, but when I exclude the js, the thing still wont get my animation-play-state: paused... Like that sentence wasn't there...